# Remove underscore followed by 7 numbers in a string?

Tags: php, regex

I know that this regex will match 1 capital character and 7 following digits.

```
^[A-Z]\d{7}$
```

How can I use PHP to remove 1 underscore followed by 7 digits from the end of a string?

I have tried `$str = preg_replace('_\d{7}', '$1$2', $html);`, which gave me the error `No ending delimiter '_' found.` I changed it to `$str = preg_replace('_\d{7}_', '$1$2', $html);`, which also did not work.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the placeholder for capital letters with an underscore?

Comment: Examples of input/output will be most welcomed!

Comment: How can you know how to make the original regexp, but not know how to create this one? What makes you think underscores are special?

Comment: I don't think it is off topic, just badly worded - the question is actually "How do I remove this pattern from the end of a string in PHP?". The OP has tried something which failed because of a PHP quirk - see comments on my answer. I have suggested an edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather obviously, it's `^_\d{7}$`.

Note that this will match a String that consists of *only* an underscore followed by seven digits. If you want to allow that pattern anywhere in a string, you could use just `_\d{7}`.

[Regex Pal](http://regexpal.com/) is a good tool for trying out regexes quickly.

Edit based on OP's comment: To remove this pattern from the end of a string in PHP, use: `preg_replace('/(.+?)_\d{7}$/', '$1', $in);`

Comment: Yes, I would ask you how to remove them from this type of string "details_clsfd_4318996".So your edited answer did this, right?

Comment: `$str = preg_replace('_\d{7}', '$1$2', $html);` gave me a No ending delimiter '_' found.
I changed it to these `$str = preg_replace('_\d{7}_', '$1$2', $html);`

Comment: I am not a PHP person, but I think something like `preg_replace("(.+?)_\\d{7}$", "$1", "details_clsfd_4318996")` would do it (assuming the underscore and 7 digits are always at the end of the string)

Comment: Update on the above - PHP wants you to wrap regexes in '/' characters - use `preg_replace('/(.+?)_\d{7}$/', '$1', $input)`

Comment: I used `_\d{7}_` but it removes all the numbers matched with or without an underscore.Your updated answer doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Works fine for me - `echo preg_replace('/(.+?)_\d{7}$/', '$1', 'details_clsfd_4318996')` outputs `details_clsfd`.